# Azure Databricks: This cluster's runtime version is out of support

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Anyone else had this error message on an **Azure Databricks cluster**:

```
'This cluster's runtime version is out of support. Select a new runtime and restart this cluster. [Learn more]'
```

("Learn more" leads to this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/databricks-runtime-ver)

The cluster has the following attributes/versions on it:

```
DBR 6.5 ML
Spark 2.4.5
Scala 2.11
```

Is there anything I can do about this error message myself, or should I contact an administrator who could update the cluster, or something like that?

Comment: https://community.talend.com/s/article/Azure-Databricks-LTS-Runtime-end-of-support-3XJ0K found this link with the information `Root Cause You are using an EOS version of Databricks.`

Answer (score 3):

Just ignore it - it will continue to run until you destroy it. But you won't be able to select this version in UI anymore, so for future clusters you'll need some other version - look for LTS versions, like, 6.4, etc.  Although it's better to start to think about migration to DBR 7.x with Spark 3 - it has a lot of optimizations that will make data processing more effective.